# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" when trying to make 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I'm so kind of new to python (and coding) and I just want to create a board (for a console game) based on the player desire.

Basically it's this...

```python
import array 
print("What size do you want the board?") 
Boardsize = input()
Tablero = array('b' [Boardsize, Boardsize])
for w in Boardsize:
    for h in Boardsize:
        Boardsize(w)(h).append('.')
print (Tablero)
```

At least that's my idea, but the compiler say:

```
Tablero = array('b'[Boardsize, Boardsize])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: 1st: you should use a list. 2nd: you should separate arguments with a comma `,`

Answer (score 20):

**What's going on**

`input()` returns a string (the characters you typed in, e.g. "123"), but you are getting a `TypeError` because you are passing a string to something that expects a number (e.g. 123, without the quotes).

---

**Solution**

The fix is convert the string to a number by passing it through the `int(...)` constructor, e.g. `int(input())` (just like `int("12")` will give you `12`).

I'd like to apologize if you are not new to programming and this was a silly mistake, but in case you are new, here was my thought process which helped me debug the issue. I hope you do not find it condescending; I am sharing my thought process so others in similar situations can fix similar bugs.

---

**How to diagnose these kinds of issues**

You would debug this as follows by backtracking one step at a time:

� *First test to make sure that you understand how to make `array`s properly. I would for example try to make an array of size 3x3 to make sure I understood the API.*

```
>>> array(..., [3,3])
<array object at 0x...>
```

� *Okay, that worked! We seem to be able to make `array`s properly if I just type in the numbers `array(..., [3,3])`. Now let's try with `input()`.*

```
>>> boardsize = input()
>>> array(..., [boardsize, boardsize])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

� *This is odd. I just made a 3x3 array with `array(..., [3,3])`, why doesn't `array(..., [boardsize, boardsize])` work? Let's check what the value of `boardsize` really is:*

```
>>> boardsize
'3'
```

� *How odd, the value seems to be `3`, right? Let me double-check to make sure.*

```
>>> boardsize == 3
False
```

� *Wait, '3'!=3 ??? How is '3' not the same as 3?*

```
>>> type(boardsize)
<class 'str'>
```

� *Ahah! The `'` I see mean it is a string. It must be the case that `input` returns a string. This makes sense, since for example I could type in "cat" and make `boardsize == 'cat'`, and I should not expect python to be able to tell whether an arbitrary string is a number.*

```
>>> '3'
'3'
>>> 3
3
>>> boardsize
'3'
```

� *The fix would be to google for `python convert string to number`: second hit: "use the built-in `int(...)` function*

**tl;dr: Work your way backwards towards the error, sanity-checking yourself at each step. When you start making large programs, you can use automatically-called sanity check functions and "unit tests" to make debugging easier.**

---

(sidenote: If you are curious how objects are printed out, it comes from the special `__repr__` method that all classes define. Calling `repr(something)` will show fairly unambiguously what kind of object `something` is; `repr` is automatically called on the output of what you type into the interactive interpreter.)

Comment: But doesn't really answer his question.

Comment: And I doubt he understands what the hell str.__repr__ means. Nor would a programmer at this level have the clairvoyance to do such a thorough debugging. I prefer to teach by example.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why someone downvoted. @machine yearning: 1) I disagree that novice programmers can't learn debugging. In my humble opinion, it is what one should first teach. 2) I further disagree that I did not answer his question (I explicitly gave a fix). Your way is perhaps fine; but my rationale is "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime" =)

Comment: @ninjagecko: I downvoted; I hope I didn't offend you. I don't usually downvote, but I think it's inappropriate to offer a series of debugging steps that I don't think he'll understand the logic behind. I tend to offer very thorough explanations when it comes to answering novice questions. In my humble opinion it's important for someone at this level to see examples of code that works, along with explanations behind the logic of the code. I think your way is more analogous to showing him how to gut the fish once he gets it. He'll never learn how to debug if he doesn't know what to look for :)

Comment: @ninjagecko: however I concede that your intention was good, so please allow me to offer what I think is a more useful debugging answer of my own, below. I will retract my downvote if you edit your answer, it's too late for me to do so right now otherwise.

Comment: @machine yearning: No thank you, I disagree with your analogy, and I think my explanation is sufficiently clear. But nevertheless I might spruce it up a bit, since it could be clearer; I am capable of making those edits myself.

Comment: @ninjagecko: I didn't mean I wanted to change your answer. I was simply offering my own opinion; like I said, I think you put forth a very thoughtful answer, but I just didn't think it was helpful when I first read it. Now that you mention it, I do agree that my answer made it inappropriately easy for him, and in the future I'll try to offer clues and resources instead of rewriting his code. I apologize for making a snap-judgment about your intentions, and I hope you can see my perspective that increased clarity is also useful. Cheers :)

Comment: ninjagecko: both you and machine yearning gave a thorough and worthy answer. You answered the question to the letter (i.e the error message); machine yearning answered to the spirit (i.e the real issue). Since the OP has stated their little-to-none programming experience, machine yearning's answer is more helpful.

Comment: thankyou! I didn't know of the type(var) and I finally found out why my stuff wasn't working :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer an answer that I think will help you debug. You said you got the error:

```
Tablero = array('b'[Boardsize, Boardsize])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Consider the content of the error. The index operator is square brackets immediately after a variable, `myvar[n]`, and whatever `n` you put in between those square brackets will be considered an index of that variable `myvar`. You usually index what are called "sequence types" (that is, `list`, `tuple`, and `string`) with integer indices. The message after your `TypeError` indicates that your code tried to index a string with something other than an integer. Here's an example that you can try yourself in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> mystr = 'cool beans, bro!' # define a string (sequence type)
>>> mystr                    # echo the value of the string by entering its name
'cool beans, bro!'

>>> mystr[0] # sequence indices start at 0, so this gives us the first character
'c' 

>>> mystr[6] # similarly, the seventh character (index 6)
'e'

>>> mystr['cool story, sis!'] # a string is not a valid index of a string
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

But where in your code, you say, did you try to index a string? Well, putting square brackets immediately after any variable makes python assume you're trying to access a value at some index of it. Your code says `'b'[Boardsize, Boardsize]`. If you want to pass both `'b'` and `[Boardsize, Boardsize]` as parameters to your `array` constructor, you'll need to put a comma between these values, like:

```
Tablero = array('b', [Boardsize, Boardsize])
```

However I would caution against using the `array` type at all, unless you think you have a very good reason to. It's tough to see the logic of this, especially coming from some other programming paradigms, but in python it's much simpler to stick with the generic `list` data structure when you can get away with it. A `list` is much like an `array` but in the latter you have to tell it what size data you'll be giving it ahead of time, which is usually unnecessarily specific except when trying to highly optimize with respect memory management. To define a list it's as simple as:

```
tablero = [ ]
```

Note two things here. First, as a convention in python, most variable names should be `lowercase` or `lower_with_underscores`. Second, the square brackets *not immediately after a variable* in this context mean something entirely different from the indexing operator: they denote a `list` constructor, meaning that any comma-separated values inside the brackets become the values of a new list. So the expression

```
[Boardsize, Boardsize]
```

would give you a list containing two values (Boardsize and Boardsize, respectively). I'll leave it to you to figure out how to use the `list` type to suit your needs, try the [brief tutorial in the official documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), and note also that you can make nested lists.

Thanks to ninjagecko for helping me brainstorm a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the example code

```
Tablero = array('b'[Boardsize, Boardsize])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Integer indices are not allowed. To get it working you can declare the DICT as specified below:

```
Tablero = {}
Tablero = array('b'[Boardsize, Boardsize])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Hope this works for you.